# CSV rows and columns calculating

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like:

```
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
6,6,6
.,.,.
.,.,.
```

`3` columns, `n` rows

I want to check 2 rows at a time if the value in the last column are the same.

Does anybody have an idea how to program this?

Comment: What have you got so far? Where are you having difficulties? Were you able to open the csv file? Were you able to read the contents? Your question is far too broad to be answered in this context - we're not going to complete your entire task for you - you'll have to show some level of research effort.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I imagine the csv module would be a good place to start.

Comment: i'm trying to put list into array                                 for line in input_3.readlines():
    list=line.split(',')
    time=list[3]
    
    
array=np.asarray(time)
print(array)

Comment: but i get message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\alg2\src\alg3.py", line 66, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: It seems that numpy is not installed. Honestly, do you need numpy for that? Also, it would probably be `list[2]`.

Comment: BTW: use module `csv` to read csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I use `StringIO` to simulate file)

Using two loops to compare any two rows:

```
data = '''2,2,2
3,3,3
6,6,6
0,0,3
4,4,4
0,0,6'''

from StringIO import StringIO

import csv

#f = open('filename.csv')
#csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

csv_reader = csv.reader(StringIO(data))

rows = list(csv_reader)

#print rows

for index_a, a in enumerate(rows[:-1]):
    for index_b, b in enumerate(rows[index_a+1:], index_a+1):
        if a[2] == b[2] :
            print "the same:", index_a, index_b, a, b
```

result

```
the same: 1 3 ['3', '3', '3'] ['0', '0', '3']
the same: 2 5 ['6', '6', '6'] ['0', '0', '6']
```

---

**EDIT:** using `pandas`

```
data = '''2,2,2
3,3,3
6,6,6
0,0,3
4,4,4
0,0,6'''

from StringIO import StringIO

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=None, header=None)

print '\n all rows \n'
print df

print '\n group by column 2 \n'

for name, gr in df.groupby(2):
    print '\n name: %s \n' % name
    print gr
    print 'indexes:', gr.index
```

result:

```
 all rows 

   0  1  2
0  2  2  2
1  3  3  3
2  6  6  6
3  0  0  3
4  4  4  4
5  0  0  6

 group by column 2 


 name: 2 

   0  1  2
0  2  2  2
indexes: Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')

 name: 3 

   0  1  2
1  3  3  3
3  0  0  3
indexes: Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')

 name: 4 

   0  1  2
4  4  4  4
indexes: Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')

 name: 6 

   0  1  2
2  6  6  6
5  0  0  6
indexes: Int64Index([2, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: @Klemen I add example with `pandas`